# Peer to Peer communication in Java

Tags: java, networking, tcp, udp, p2p

I am trying to develop a simple Peer to Peer chat using Java. I coded the idea using Java Sockets. Please find the code below and check whether I started correctly or not. Please tell me any other suggestions or Feedback to improve. I used TCP, is it correct to use TCP for P2P? Or should I use UDP?

Thanks in advance.

//Peer.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


class Peer {

int port;

Peer () {


    try {
        
        System.out.print("Enter port for this Peer  ");
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        port = Integer.parseInt(din.readLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO: handle exception
    }

}

class Sender extends Thread {

    Socket s;
    public void run() {

        try {

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter destPort  ");
            int destPort = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

            s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", destPort);
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {

                System.out.println("Enter message for another peer  ");
                String str = in.readLine();
                dout.writeUTF(str);

                System.out.println("Message sent");

                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {

                    din.readUTF();
                    this.run();
                    break;
                }
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class Receiver extends Thread {

    int port;
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s;
    DataInputStream din;
    DataOutput dout;

    Receiver(int port) {

        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Receiver created!!!");

            s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");

            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {

                String str = din.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Message from Client is " + str);
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {

                    System.out.println("Client left");
                    dout.writeUTF(str);
                    s.close();
                    ss.close();
                    this.run();
                    break;
                }
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

public void newPeer() throws Exception {

    Sender s = new Sender();
    Receiver r = new Receiver(port);

    s.start(); r.start();

    s.join(); r.join();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Peer p = new Peer();
    p.newPeer();
}}
```

I run this code in two terminals and here is the output.

Terminal1:

```
java Peer
Enter port for this Peer  2001
Enter destPort
Receiver created!!!
Client connected
Message from Client is hello
2002
Enter message for another peer
Hello
Message sent
Enter message for another peer
Message from Client is bye
Client left
Receiver created!!!
```

Terminal 2:

```
java Peer
Enter port for this Peer  2002
Enter destPort
Receiver created!!!
2001
Enter message for another peer
hello
Message sent
Enter message for another peer
Client connected
Message from Client is Hello
bye
Message sent
Enter destPort
```

Comment: *" I used TCP, is it correct to use TCP for P2P"* mainly depends on what your application sends, not on the architecture of the network. Very simplified: if you can lose some packets but you need them fast use UDP; if you need all packets to reach their destination use TCP.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks, Got the point. Please check whether the above code is the correct way to implement P2P?

Comment: I'm a little confused why there is no reply. If you have any problem of the answer, please tell me so that we can improve it. If it's helpful to you, can you please give me a useful upvote or acception? That's important for me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to realise p2p by TCP, you need to use C/S mode for each side: every peer is a server and it is also a client. That is why we always use UDP to do that, it's relatively simple.

What's more, your program can only work in LAN. If you want these peers to communicate in WLAN, you may need NAT traversal tools like STUN/TURN/ICE.